# Suggestions for jQuery-based Date/Time Selector

Tags: jquery, ajax, datepicker, timepicker

I'm in search for a jQuery-based Date/Time Selector.  I have found a few that are quite nice, but one of my requirements is that I can provide a json/xml/etc source of available days/times and the control should only allow selections of available days/times.

Is anyone aware of a plugin that does this, or at least a plugin that could be modified to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use jQuery UI's datepicker in conjunction with a plugin from Martin Milesich. It's a *fantastic* way to implement timepicking right next to the datepicking. It looks like the plugin has gone offline, but I uploaded the script so you can download it here: http://textsnip.com/19046f

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

It's very easy to implement. Just call the regular `datepicker()` method from jQuery UI and add a `showTime: true` parameter. Here is a sample:

```
$('#sample').datepicker({
  duration: '',
  showTime: true,
  constrainInput: false,
  stepMinutes: 1,
  stepHours: 1,
  altTimeField: '',
  time24h: false
});
```

Comment: hi, I need this timepicker but can't found script. Can you help me please. (I need Combined script)

Answer (score 0):

This plugin is pretty good and it should satisfy your requirements.
http://keith-wood.name/datepickRef.html

Notice `onDate` method: it allows you to control presentation of each particular date, including whether date is selectable or not.